# Dismissing QLPreviewController crashes: Auto Layout still required

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an iPad app with a `SplitViewController`. In my `DetailViewController`, there is a button which is used to present a `QLPreviewController` and show a document. Everything works fine so far, however, when I dismiss the preview controller using the `Done` button on the top left, the app throws an exception with the following error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UIView.m:5781
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after sending -viewDidLayoutSubviews to the view controller. DetailViewController's implementation needs to send -layoutSubviews to the view to invoke auto layout.'
*** First throw call stack: (...)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Here is how I implemented the presentation of `QLPreviewController` and its delegate methods:

```
- (IBAction)previewButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    QLPreviewController *ql = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
    ql.dataSource = self;
    ql.delegate = self;
    ql.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0;
    [self presentViewController:ql animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.documentFilePath];
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller
{
    return 1;
}
```

and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:self.gridView.frame.size]; // if not called, the contentSize of UIScrollView is wrong.
}
```

`DetailViewController` contains a `UIScrollView` and it has a custom `UIView` (gridView) as subview and the gridView has many subviews.

While testing, I commented out the line of code that sets the content size from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, and by doing so, I could successfully dismiss the preview controller. However, this only works before I add `gridView` as a subview to `scrollView`. After adding it as a subview, it crashes again on dismissal. This time I get `EXC_BREAKPOINT` error and no log on the console. The output from debugger is as follows:

```
CoreFoundation`CFHash:
0x4597740:  pushl  %ebp
0x4597741:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x4597743:  pushl  %edi
0x4597744:  pushl  %esi
0x4597745:  subl   $16, %esp
0x4597748:  calll  0x459774d                 ; CFHash + 13
0x459774d:  popl   %edi
0x459774e:  movl   8(%ebp), %esi
0x4597751:  testl  %esi, %esi
0x4597753:  jne    0x459776b                 ; CFHash + 43
0x4597755:  int3   
0x4597756:  calll  0x46eca00                 ; symbol stub for: getpid  <-  EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
0x459775b:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x459775e:  movl   $9, 4(%esp)
0x4597766:  calll  0x46eca4e                 ; symbol stub for: kill
...
```

As a note, the app is targeting iOS 6 and using auto layout.

I wonder if anyone can help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with QLPreviewController. You probably needn't even have shown the code for it. The problem seems to be purely your underlying view controller's layout. Layout is needed only because the QLPreviewController was dismissed, but the same problem would presumably happen if *any* presented view controller had been dismissed, thus revealing your view controller's view.

Comment: Well, before switching to modal `QLPreviewController`, I was using a segue to a PageSheet view controller and an `UIWebView`. There was no issue back then.

Comment: The reason why I included the code is that this is the first time I am using `QLPreviewController`, and wanted to make sure that I am not doing something wrong.

Comment: Well, I'm a little surprised there was no issue when you came back from the page sheet view controller. But hey, layout can be weird. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `viewDidLayoutSubviews` implementation, do what the error message tells you to do: call `[self.view layoutSubviews]`. See if that helps.

**EDIT**: It may be that my suggestion in the preceding paragraph should be to call `layoutIfNeeded` rather than `layoutSubviews`.

Another thing to try, if that doesn't work: move the whole content size setting thing to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` instead of doing it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: It didn't help, same exception error: `Auto Layout still required...`.

Comment: Oh blast, my answer is totally wrong and misleading. Sorry. Check my edited answer and see if that's better. Sorry again.

Comment: It's OK. In your edited answer, your first suggestion works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: As a second note, I also tried to move the content size setting code to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` as I thought it belongs there, but I again faced the `EXC_BREAKPOINT` issue.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I was moving too fast and thought that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` was `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution again. Just to clarify, isn't it kind of absurd to call `layoutSubviews` after it has been already done? Actually I would expect some kind of a loop, you know calling it again and again...

Comment: That's what I was saying about calling super in `layoutSubviews`. It is legal and doesn't cause a loop. All it does is tell autolayout to look at all the constraints again and adjust the frames accordingly. It doesn't trigger anything so there is no loop.

Comment: You should really call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` here instead of `[self.view layoutSubviews]`. [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews) explicitly say you should not call `layoutSubviews` directly.

Comment: No, @pasta12, you've misunderstood. (1) The error message explicitly says: "DetailViewController's implementation needs to send `layoutSubviews` to the view to invoke auto layout." So it's saying, yes, send it! (2) You certainly _can_ send `layoutSubviews` at one special time: _during layout_. And that is exactly what's going on here.

Comment: I disagree. The method is only meant to be overridden. The layoutSubviews docs say "If you want to update the layout of your views immediately, call the layoutIfNeeded method" and "If you want to force a layout update, call the setNeedsLayout method instead to do so prior to the next drawing update".