# UIScrollView inside UIPageViewController doesn't respond to swipe when scrolled for first time

Tags: uiscrollview, scroll, swipe, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController that contains a UIScrollView as follow:

> **UIPageViewController**
>   -->UIView
>   -->**UIScrollView**
>   -->UIPageControl

The problem is that I encountered a weird behavior whereby when the whole view **first shown** in XCode Simulator, I cannot swipe the UIScrollView and it turned out that the UIPageViewController is being swiped to second page. However, after the UIPageViewController turned to second page, now the UIScrollView are able to swiped! Anyone know whether this is delegation problem or any other problem? Your advice is much appreciated.

Comment: After repetitive testing, I just found out that my scrollview's contentSize is 0 when the viewDidAppear for the first time.

Comment: Thus, I plan to set the UIScrollView's contentSize at viewDidLayoutSubViews, however, it returned an error message as follow : Assertion failure in -[UIView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UIView.m:5781
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after sending -viewDidLayoutSubviews to the view controller. XXXXViewController's implementation needs to send -layoutSubviews to the view to invoke auto layout.'

Comment: [SOLUTION]
Credit to this question
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846325/dismissing-qlpreviewcontroller-crashes-auto-layout-still-required)